# What is a good DTD for 1360x768@60?

Tags: windows, graphics-card, intel-graphics

Intel graphics drivers can pump out custom resolutions but they require a VESA DTD (Detailed Timing Descriptor). What's a reasonable one for 1360x768@60Hz (the highest resolution accepted over VGA by my Toshiba TV)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`66 21 50 B0 51 00 1B 30 40 70 37 00 00 00 00 00 00 18`

By plugging in the 1360x768 modeline from [the mythtv wiki's modeline database](http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Modeline_Database#EDID_modelines_from_HDTVs)

Comment: This works for our EEE PC and looks noticeably better than 1280x768. Calculated by and inserted into the registry with the DTD Calculator.

Comment: Could use a little adjusting, the right side of the image is not picked up by the monitor.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it myself, but here is what I've found: [DTD Calculator](http://members.cox.net/archibael/setupdtd100.exe).

And [here](http://www.avsforum.com/avs-vb/showthread.php?t=947830) is how to use it.